# Copy spreadsheet with google sheets api enabled

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm currently using google apps script and google sheets api only for creating pivot tables inside the spreadsheet.

With that, I've created a template spreadsheet which I can copy from again and again. What I'm wondering is, is it possible to enable the google sheets api (for the copied spreadsheets) without going to the google API console everytime?

Comment: As in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812240/copy-google-spreadsheet-prompts-authorization-every-time, you make a new Apps Script project with each copy. These projects cannot execute without authorization. Consider changing your project design to use a webapp (that you activate the Sheets API for), and with your webapp, pick the sheet to create your pivot table in.  (PS: Pivot Table constructs were recently revealed in the native `SpreadsheetApp`, [on Apr 11](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-table), so you might be able to rewrite anyway)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Another thing.. I was just reading the pivot table reference, and it seems I still need to use the API to actually generate the pivot table, is that correct?